# C99 single line comparitive syntax shortcut

Tags: c, syntax, shortcut, c99

I don't have a compiler handy to check this myself.

1. Is the code in Version 1 (below) valid in C C99? Will the it compile and run ok?
2. Is it logically equivalent to the code in Version 2?

**Version 1:**

```
int a, b, c, d;

... some code to set the above variables ...

if (a != b != c != d)
    //Do something

... rest of code ...
```

**Version 2:**

```
int a, b, c, d;

... some code to set the above variables ...

if ((a != b) && (a != c) && (a != d) && (b != c) && (b != d) && (c != d))
    //Do something

... rest of code ...
```

Comment: If you are online there are several [online compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) available and at least with Coliru and ideone it is straight forward to use C99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `!=` is associated from left to right:

```
if (a != b != c != d)
```

can be translated to

```
if (((a != b) != c) != d)
```

But the result is not what you expected, e.g, given `a = 100, b = 200;`, then `a != b` is `0`, because any true value is evaluated as `1`, false value as `0`. So to your question:

> Is the code in Version 1 (below) valid in C C99? Will the it compile and run ok?
>   Is it logically equivalent to the code in Version 2?

It is valid, but it's not equivalent to the code in Version 2.

Answer (score 2):

The first program is valid C code.

It is not equivalent to the second program as the result of the `!=` operator is either `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is check whether the four variables all have different values, then the second version is correct. Because of right-left associativity of the logical operators, the first version will be parsed as:

```
if (((a != b) != c) != d)
```

so you'll end up checking whether `d` is equal to some value that is either zero or one.